# python 2.7 regex search at pos where '^' starts at pos

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This may have been asked already but I can't seem to find any duplicates so I am going to ask myself and hope I don't get flagged.

I am building a small parser using a state machine that switches into a sub-parser whenever a `{` is detected. I only want the very first occurrence of what my regex will match at the position I am currently at. Basically my regex is `keymatch = re.compile(r'^\{([A-Za-z0-9])\}')` and I am using the string `this {is} a {test} string`.

The problem is I am getting no match when I run `keymatch.match(myString, pos)` I have also tried with `keymatch.search(myString, pos)` and found the same result.

For the record, pos is pointing at the correct location, hard coded values also return none, while no position or leading `^` in my regex returns all the matches, which I do not want because of how I am rebuilding the string character by character. In addition, if a match is not found at pos, I want my match object to be `none` to trigger an error rather than just give me anything down the string it finds.

Is anything noticeably wrong with my approach, and if so, what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is indicating the beginning of the string. So it is only searching for the first character being an open bracket. You can remove the `^`

Comment: Just updated my post since I realize I did not properly explain. I only want the very first occurrence at pos. When searching, pos is pointing at the `{`, is there a way to search for and return a match if it exists at the beginning of pos and a `none` otherwise to trigger an error?

Comment: I take it back for I am a fool, removing the `^` and using `.match` does exactly what I need. I am not stellar with regex's and pythons re module adds just enough weirdness to throw me off track. You were correct, thank you!